# javascript if (a.b.v.c.d.e === true)

Tags: javascript

What's an easy way to check

```
if (a.b.v.c.d.e === true) {}
```

and return false if any of b or c or v is undefined?

Coffeescript handles it easily but what is a comparable solution in vanilla javascript? Is there a library that has this common issue taken cared of?

Comment: `if (_.get(a, 'b.c.v.c.d.e'))` with lodash.

Comment: What about `if ( undefined !== a.b.c.d.e && true === a.b.c.d.e ) { }` If you try to access any value that doesn't exists will return `undifined`.

Comment: @Merianos, if either `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` is undefined, the code you posted will throw an exception.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if any of those is `undefined` by value ?

Comment: @Merianos, if they exist and are bound to `undefined`, or if they don't exist in the "parent" object.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. ;)

Comment: @elclanrs thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have a pretty feature to do this (without using any helper functions). You can use `&&` operator to do this:

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.v && a.b.v.c && a.b.v.c.d && a.b.v.c.d.e === true) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` to express the chained dependencies.

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.v && a.b.v.c && a.b.v.c.d && a.b.v.c.d.e === true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function and call it like this:

```
if (ignoreNulls(a, 'b', 'v', 'c', 'd', 'e') == true) {
  // ...
}


function ignoreNulls() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var subj = args.shift();
  while (prop = args.shift()) {
    var v = subj[prop];
    if (v !== null && v != undefined) {
      subj = v
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return subj;
}
```